# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on Tensorflow tests execution

Tags: java, tensorflow, bazel

Executing Tensorflow test suite using command:

```
bazel test //tensorflow/...
```

throws Out of memory issue:

```
INFO: Found 1886 targets and 1155 test targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 291.775s, Critical Path: 0.91s
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.SkyKey.create(SkyKey.java:57)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ArtifactSkyKey.key(ArtifactSkyKey.java:43)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.toKeys(ActionExecutionFunction.java:576)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.compute(ActionExecutionFunction.java:158)
        at com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.ParallelEvaluator$Evaluate.run(ParallelEvaluator.java:370)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.concurrent.AbstractQueueVisitor$WrappedRunnable.run(AbstractQueueVisitor.java:501)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Java heap space

bazel ran out of memory and crashed.
```

I have tried below options still issue persists.

> export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
>
> export JVM_ARGS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
>
> export JVM_ARGS="-XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

Also, changed the file from bazel code: scripts/bootstrap/compile.sh

`" run "${JAVAC}" -J-Xms1g -J-Xmx1g -classpath "${classpath}" -sourcepath "${sourcepath}"`"

Machine configurations: Ubuntu distribution, openjdk8, RAM 16G

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `JAVA_OPTIONS` with the correct name and without quotes characters :

```
JAVA_OPTIONS= -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

If it doesn't work, maybe the JAVA_OPTIONS env variable is not used. 
You could try to specify directly the arguments in the execution command.
[According to the official documentation](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--host_jvm_args), you could do :

```
bazel test --host_jvm_args=-Xms512m --host_jvm_args=-Xmx1024m //tensorflow/...
```

Comment: Thanks! Below command worked for me:                                               `bazel  --host_jvm_args="-Xms512m" --host_jvm_args="-Xmx1024m"  test //tensorflow/...`